# How can I get the NUnit CodeFixVerifier to correctly test winforms code?

Tags: c#, winforms, nunit, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing a Roslyn analyzer which must (unfortunately) do some analysis on code using winforms. I am having trouble writing unit tests for this analyzer because I cannot get the test state to include the appropriate references or project properties in a nice way.

I have some test code like:

```
.
.
.
using VerifyCS = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Testing.NUnit.CodeFixVerifier<
    MyAnalzyer,
    MyCodeFixProvider>;
.
.
.
[Test]
        public async Task MyAnalyzerUnitTest()
        {
            var test = @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CatchBlockAnalyzerTest
{
    public class TestUserForm : Form
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {           
        }
    }
}
";
FileLinePositionSpan Span = ... //Determine correct span here;
DiagnosticResult expected = VerifyCS.Diagnostic("MyAnalyzer").WithSpan(Span).WithArguments("MyArguments");
```

If I run the test as it is above, the test fails because in addition to the expected diagnostic I also get the following:

```
// /0/Test0.cs(3,22): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
DiagnosticResult.CompilerError("CS0234").WithSpan(3, 22, 3, 27).WithArguments("Forms", "System.Windows")
```

I have seen this kind of thing when using windows forms in some versions of .NET (.Net Core for instance) and in those cases I cannot just add references to winforms. What I have to do is add/change the following entries in the .csproj file.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
.
.
.
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
.
.
.
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However, I have not been able to figure out how to make those same changes to the virtual workspace that is created by the codefix verifier. I believe I can do something equivalent to setting the target framework property by the following:

```
CSharpCodeFixTest<MyAnalyzer, MyCodeFixProvider, NUnitVerifier> FixTest = new CSharpCodeFixTest<MyAnalyzer, MyCodeFixProvider, NUnitVerifier>
            {

                TestState =
                {
                    Sources = { test },
                    ExpectedDiagnostics = { expected }
                }

            };
            
            FixTest.TestState.ReferenceAssemblies = new ReferenceAssemblies("net6.0-windows");
            await FixTest.RunAsync()
```

I have no idea how to assign to the UseWindowsForms property.

One thing that does work is manually adding a metadata reference to a particular winforms .dll on my hard drive using the following code:

```
FixTest.TestState.AdditionalReferences.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile("C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\shared\\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\\3.1.32\\System.Windows.Forms.dll"));
```

It has to be a version less than 4.2.2 because otherwise I get the following diagnostic in my test output:

```
error CS1705: Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms' with identity 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' uses 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives' with identity 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
DiagnosticResult.CompilerError("CS1705").WithArguments("System.Windows.Forms", "System.Windows.Forms, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", "System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.ComponentModel.Primitives", "System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
```

This does create the desired behavior but I hate having a hardcoded path in my test code and am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

In short, I would like my unit test to path with only the expected diagnostic being generated. How can I set up the test environment to make this happen in a way that can be easily reproduced on other machines (ie not hardcode paths)?